# How to implement Bayesian Model Combination?

Tags: bayesian, model-averaging, forecast-combination

I'm interested in formal procedure mentioned in ["Turning Bayesian Model Averaging Into Bayesian Model Combination"](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/papers/Kristine.ijcnn2011.pdf) (Kristine Monteith 2011). I have a set of $N$ "best" AIC ranked models and I want to combine forecasts of $n \le N$ models, to do so I need to chose $n$, I also need to chose number of combinations in each diversified ensemble $c \le n$.

My question is how to determine "optimal" $n$ and $c$? My goal is to maximize forecasting performance but I do not want to generate overfitted combination.

Comment: Łukasz, I edited your question -- please check if everything is ok. Notice that this site enables you to use $\TeX$ formatting for formulas.

Comment: I've worked with Raftery's model averaging a bit, but I know nothing of model combination. However, frequently the answer to the question of "how to choose optimal" anything is cross-validation, especially in Machine Learning.

Comment: CV is best but it is also very computationaly expensive. The philosophy behind AIC is to "go around" cross validation. I was thinking more about calculating "AIC of combined models" and use this to compare different BMC(n,c) forecasts, or something like that.